# How do I get rid of old encrypted home folder?

Tags: encryption, directory, home-directory, delete

The encrypted home folder is taking up a lot of space. It's a home folder of an account before I updated via USB, I've copied all the files over from it and I need to know how to delete it, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type into a terminal "sudo su" then "sudo nautilus" then go into the /home/ directory and delete the folder from there.

Comment: It's in /tmp and the folder is encryptfs.FKt63n, it gives me an error when I try to delete it. "there was an error deleting encryptfs.FKt63n."

Comment: Is it already in the trash? If so then empty it, it acts the same as the windows recycle bin

Comment: It's not there. Also, it's not my home folder. It's my last account's home folder. I have no problem opening it via "sudo ecryptfs-recover-private"

Comment: If you can open it then try deleting just the contents

Comment: I've tried. That option is grayed out. I tried looking through some commands using the prefix encryptfs and almost made my computer unusable, heh. Whoops.

Comment: Well, Thanks you've actually given me an Idea. This'll either destroy what I call my hard drive or rid my of my problems. :)

Comment: Wait... What? What are you going to do?

Comment: You helped me. I deleted a folder here "/home/.encryptfs/USERNAME/.Private" It had a "." infront of it and "ctrl + H" was disabled I just got scared because I already broke it today! XD Thanks!